# Ultimate Home Development setup - massive desktop w/ thin client laptop? POSSIBLE?

Tags: hardware

I'm trying to figure out the best lower-budget home office development hardware setup. My laptop is aging.

My latest idea is that I would like a very powerful desktop paired with a less-powerful laptop. The idea being that the desktop would do the heavy lifting while the laptop would allow me to work untethered (but within range of the wireless network, of course.)

Is such a thing possible, or am I dreaming?

(I develop .Net applications - mostly Asp.Net)

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Really, this is thinly veiled as programming related, but it is just a  question about thin clients...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with an RDP / Terminal Services client or VNC. You could also run multiple virtual machines on the beefy server (making it look like a poor man's datacentre / set of less powerful servers).

Another benefit is that you can do some testing with the laptop as the browser client and the desktop as server - this can sometimes show up issues that you won't see with testing on localhost (especially if your network goes down in the middle of it).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to run multiple virtual machines and still terminal service in? Is Remote Desktop the same thing as Terminal Services?

Comment: I think RDP is just a rebranded TS, maybe wrong. And yes, you can run multiple VMs, each will look like physical machines on your network alongside the real machine. You can RDP to any of them. Get plenty of memory in the real machine. See virtualbox.org or vmware.com for some free VM options.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this makes sense and this will work.  It's a similar model (but not the same) that's been used for unix workstations in the past (X window).

Answer (score 1):

I would keep your aging laptop to use for testing thin client apps - who cares if it's aging how much power does it need to run Internet Explorer?

My dream development system at this moment in time would look something like this:

- A couple of nice fast dual core processors
- 4 Gigs of memory
- A couple of Intel X25-M 180Gb Solid State Hard Disks to run my apps off.
- 3 x 19+" high contrast ratio monitors, these 3 I have on my desk are wicked.
- Ergonomic keyboard, I currently have the Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 which I quite like
- Wireless Laser Mouse, I currently use the Logitech MX Revolution and I love it
- A 2Tb SATA drive for extra storage space (just in case)

Of course, I don't have any of this at home, I have an aging laptop just like you.  I have part of this setup on my desk at work and I keep drooling over the other bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the desktop as some kind of a server and let both your desktop and your laptop compile.

It's like they render 3D CGI movies in studios, across a farm of computers.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how my current setup is, and it works nicely.  I'd still get a couple of 20"+ monitors, as the laptop can be a little restricting for long usage.